# Unique values from ansible output dict's

Tags: ansible, unique

I have some servers with a lot of wordpress instances, who I ask them what versions they have.

```
- name: CONTADOR WP VERSIONES
shell: mycommand 
register: wp_versions 

- debug: msg: "{{ wp_versions.stdout_lines }}"
```

For example:

```
    TASK [debug] *********************************************************************
    ok: [server1] => {
        "msg": [
            "5.1.13"
        ]
    }
    ok: [server2] => {
        "msg": [
            "5.1.12",
            "5.1.13"
        ]
    }
    ok: [server3] => {
        "msg": [
            "5.1.10",
            "5.1.13",
        ]
    }
```

I need to list a unique values like this:

```
"msg": [
    "5.1.10",
    "5.1.12",
    "5.1.13",
]
```

I have tried all that i found but nothing works as I want.

Thanks

Comment: In what data structure are you storing those values?

Comment: I did my command with shell module and I register the output in a var. Then I use it in a debug msg.

        - name: CONTADOR WP VERSIONES
          shell: mycommand
          register: wp_versions
        
        - debug:
          msg: "{{ wp_versions.stdout_lines }}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) *ansible_play_hosts* and [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variables from the *hostvars*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        all_vers: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                      map('extract', hostvars, ['wp_versions', 'stdout_lines'])|
                      flatten|unique }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
all_vers:
  - 5.1.13
  - 5.1.12
  - 5.1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: CONTADOR WP VERSIONES
      shell: mycommand
      register: wp_versions

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    # This tasks builds a flattened list of all the
    # wp_versions.stdout_lines values collected from your hosts.
    - name: Collect wp_versions information
      set_fact:
        all_wp_versions_pre: "{{ all_wp_versions_pre + hostvars[item].wp_versions.stdout_lines }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.all }}"
      vars:
        all_wp_versions_pre: []

    # Here we use the `unique` filter to produce a list of
    # unique versions.
    - name: Set all_wp_versions fact
      set_fact:
        all_wp_versions: "{{ all_wp_versions_pre|unique }}"

    - debug:
        var: all_wp_versions
```

Given you examples, this would produce the following output:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all_wp_versions": [
        "5.1.13",
        "5.1.12",
        "5.1.10"
    ]
}
```